# Is there a Railscasts for Django?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django

I learned everything I know about Rails from Railscasts. Now I want to learn Django but I'm not finding any comprehensive tutorial resources like Railscasts. Does an equivalent not exist in the Django world? If so, is that because there is less to learn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some screencasts in the [django documentation](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DjangoScreencasts).

Answer (score 1):

I came across this website that might be what you need: https://godjango.com/

Answer (score 0):

These ones are quite old and not updated anymore: http://thisweekindjango.com/screencasts/

Answer (score 0):

I found this one -- https://www.neckbeardrepublic.com/screencasts/ -- they seem to have a good coverage on a range of topics. Hope this helps.